# How can I use a controller to control the mouse when using remote desktop to a Windows PC?

Tags: remote-access, game-controllers, mouse

Pretty much as the question!
Samsung Galaxy S7 Edge, Moga Pro Power in HID 'B' setting and microsoft remote desktop app.